# Beg for square brackets!

Tags: riddle, computer-science

> If you like snakes, beg **for** square brackets.
>
> If you are a black key, beg **from** "**in**".
>
> If you are another black key, beg **for** curly brackets.
>
> If you are fully functional, beg square brackets in a bar.
>
> If you like coffee, beg parentheses with two dots. Don't forget the filter.
>
> If you have trouble in speaking, beg parentheses in a **loop**.
>
> If you like jewels, beg parentheses with two dots. Also curly brackets if needed.
>
> If you don't have a direction, beg **for** parentheses.

What are you actually begging for?

Subtle Hint:

> The bold texts are keywords.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, second try:

> A loop

Clues I've gotten so far:

> "If you like snakes" is Python, where [] is used to create a list that can be looped through. 
>  "If you are fully functional" is Haskell, where [ (operation) | (pattern) <- list] loops through a list and performs an operation on matches 
>  "If you like coffee" is Java, where you use for (starting variable; filter; operation) to create a loop 
>  
>  "If you have trouble speaking" is Stutter, which has no special characters, thus you would just declare **loop** 
>  And "If you like jewels" is Ruby, where ({:}) can be used to generate an array that you can loop through

Comment: rot13(Gur Unfxryy bar vf pbeerpg. Tvir vg n guveq fubg!)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it iteration?

Clues:

> All of these are different programming languages.
>  Snakes: python
>  Black keys: F# and C# (keys on a piano)
>  Fully Functional: Haskell
>  Coffee: Java
>  Trouble speaking: Lisp
>  Jewels: Ruby
>  Don't have direction: Maybe Scala? As a play on Scalar (as opposed to a vector, which has direction)

Comment: rot13(Lbh tbg nyy ynathntrf pbeerpg. Tvir vg nabgure fubg.)